# ionic platform add android Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: android, installation, ionic-framework

```
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Adding android project...
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\arnold tan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1072:12)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

i have use

```
C:\your\Directory>npm link cordova

C:\your\Directory>npm link ionic
```

then go for,

```
C:\your\Directory>ionic platform add android
```

but it not working. maybe someone can help this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try running to yield more debug information.

> ionic -d platform add android

In my case, I added c:\windows\system32 to the PATH environment variable and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt as Administrator and run the command to build.It worked for me.

Comment: thanx alot buddy.

Answer (score 0):

*Do you have the Android SDK installed ?

- Do you have your environment variables Set ? 
  HOME_ANDROID="path to android sdk"

*ENOENT means that there's no entry ! so You should check if u have Admin rights to change contentes of that folder !