# Unable to add platform in ionic project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic. I am able to install ionic and also create a new project based on this link http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html.But when I try to add a platform it says failed with exit code ENOENT.

I tried to yield debug information by "ionic -d platform add android" as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32360435/5820057.

I got this [msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu4QJ.png).

What does it mean? "Failed to find bower component 'android'". Is there any issues with the CLI version?

Answer (score 0):

Android on OS X note gives you an error, searching it;
typing "?

Make sure `JAVA_HOME` is set, as well as paths to your `JDK` and `JRE` for java in browser tab" will result in cordova based errors.
means ionic is wrapper around `cordova`, so most probably `cordova` will give you the exact error.
Also make sure all required variable are available in `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I have checked the  path variable and all the variables are present. I have also set JAVA_HOME to the jdk path, but it is still not working.